# Should I use folds in Turtle or Foldl packages?

Tags: haskell, haskell-turtle

I'm having some difficulty using Turtle and only after several minutes staring at incomprehensible error messages realized that I was using wrong `fold` function.

https://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.8/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:fold
https://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.0/docs/src/Control.Foldl.html#fold

Why is there a name collision? I don't believe that's coincidence but I cannot figure it out. Are these inherently different kinds of folds?

To be concrete, I wanted to fold a stream filenames into single name using maximum of modification time.

Comment: Well they added a monadic variant, since in Turtle, you usually perform monadic actions.

Answer (score 3):

(First of all, the folds we are talking about here are not the [foldr](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldr) [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldl) [foldl'](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldl-39-) functions from `Data.Foldable`, they are from the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl) package, which is *conceptually* related to the `foldl'` function from the `Data.Foldable`, as a sort of versatile generalization, but has separate definitions.)

The [`Fold`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.0/docs/Control-Foldl.html#t:Fold) datatype repesents a strict, stateful operation to perform on an incoming sequence of values. Its `Applicative` instance lets you run two operations combined on the same sequence of values. `Fold`s have the nice property that they are agnostic about where the values come from.

Each type of source will have its own function to feed in the values. These functions *might* share the name `fold`, but it isn't a problem because the typical recommendation is to import the packages qualified.

The [fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.0/docs/Control-Foldl.html#v:fold) function from the [foldl](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/foldl-1.4.0) package feeds the contents of any `Foldable` container. The [fold](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.8/docs/Turtle-Shell.html#v:fold) from [turtle](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/turtle-1.5.8) feeds the results of a `Shell`. Streaming libraries like "pipes" have their [own adapters](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.3.9/docs/Pipes-Prelude.html#v:fold).